# js function containing php executes when not called

Tags: java, php

I have the following code within the  tag of my page:

```
<script>
    function LogInOut()
    {
        // Get the current login status
        alert("executing LogInOut");
        $loginStatus = "<?php echo $_SESSION['login']; ?>";
        if ($loginStatus == "true")
        {
            <?php
                echo "<br />script function";
                $_SESSION['login'] = "false";
                session_destroy();
            ?>
            document.getElementById("loginState").innerHTML = "login";
        }
        else
        {
            window.location = 'login.php';
        }
    }

</script>
```

I find that the php code executes when the page loads. The function (for debugging) is NEVER called yet the php code executes while none of the rest of the script executes! Can anyone clarify why this could be happening?

thank you,
Shimon

Comment: you are mixing php with javascript, php cannot be called from within a javascript function like that. to have the php code executed by that function you would have to do an ajax request to a script containing that code

Comment: You just declare a function but didn't call it. Try add this line to call that function at the bottom of your code : LogInOut();

Comment: When the js get rendered it will execute all the `PHP` codes to construct the function. Here in your case constructing your `js` function involves setting the sessions etc. Which is not the correct way of doing it. You have to write those `PHP` in a separate `PHP` file and call that using `Ajax` request.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Using an ajax call solved my issue as I needed to change the session state without refreshing the page. Not sure why I missed that...

Answer (score 1):

Classic case of mixing Javascript, a client side language, with PHP, a server side language. They run at two different locations and that being said this will never be possible.

PHP runs before javascript and if your trying to mix it with javascript, use it to echo dynamic data. eg:

```
var logged_in = <?=($_SESSION['login'] ? 'true' : 'false')?> ;
```

Javascript runs within the browser and after PHP, do not use php code thinking it will run inside of the browser

Comment: Thanks Jay for the reminder. Between you and Deepak I solved my issue...wish I could give you both credit. One of those DOH moments I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You will need something to call the function
In your case, call it when page is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     LogInOut();
});
```

Or using a console for modern browser type in:

```
LogInOut();
```